# I need the Regular Expression For Replacing Characters in a SQL Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, regex

I am trying to match the BETWEEN RANGE on this SQL Statement as found below:

```
( WAEXD8 BETWEEN &amp;WAEXD8 AND &amp;WAEXD8 )
```

The above SQL Statement works with a DBS Data-source and while effective on an iSeries Connection through the ODBC Driver for that DB connection type is not going to work for ADO.NET.  The ASP.NET ADO Connection needs to have the BETWEEN RANGE replaced with the following syntax

```
date(digits(FIELDNAME) CONCAT '000000') <= current date and date(digits(FIELDNAME) CONCAT '000000') >= current date
```

WHERE FIELDNAME is the WAEXD8 Column found in the original SQL Statement...

I have tried and as of yet haven't come close to a true solution to this...

Again, I am looking to get an ASP.NET C# Regular Expression Match/Replace for the original SQL Query to the replacement  string while keeping the original column name.  Is this possible?  What is the Pattern or example of the pattern so, that I can do this?

Possible Other Solution:

To Match ( Any number of spaces with a BETWEEN and having HTML Entity `&amp;` with )

Ex.: `([(])|([BETWEEN])*([0-9A-Za-z])*([)])`

Comment: Maybe there is not other way, but are you sure you need to use regular expression to do this? Just remember: [Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: Not another way original queries are 'readonly' from source, and I am trying to provide an automated method of cleanup.

Comment: It wouldn't normally be my approach as I don't really do regex pattern match replaces.  Generally, I rewrite the query itself or build a procedure that correctly queries the data without having to resort to gimmicky tricks to normalize the Query Syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are after but here are some examples which should cover you:

#### Replace all BETWEEN statements where they include `&amp;` and the same FIELDNAME

Will match the following:

- `( WAEXD8 BETWEEN &amp;WAEXD8 AND &amp;WAEXD8 )`
- `(WAEXD8 BETWEEN &amp;WAEXD8 AND &amp;WAEXD8)`
- `(WAEXD8 BETWEEN &amp;WAEXD8 AND &amp;WAEXD8 )`
- `( WAEXD8 BETWEEN &amp;WAEXD8 AND &amp;WAEXD8 )`
- `( FIELDEXAMPLE1 BETWEEN &amp;FIELDEXAMPLE1 AND &amp;FIELDEXAMPLE1 )`

Will not match:

- `( WAEXD8 BETWEEN WAEXD8 AND WAEXD8 )`
- `( WAEXD8 BETWEEN 0 AND 9000 )`
- `( WAEXD8 BETWEEN &amp;WAEXD8&A;NY1 AND &amp;WAEXD&8ANY2 )`
- `( FIELDEXAMPLE1 BETWEEN &amp;FIELDEXAMPLE2 AND &amp;FIELDEXAMPLE2 )`

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\(\s*(\w+)\s+BETWEEN\s+&amp;\1\s+AND\s+&amp;\1\s*\)");
resultString = regexObj.Replace(subjectString, "(date(digits($1) CONCAT '000000') <= current date and date(digits($1) CONCAT '000000') >= current date)");
```

Alternatively if you know the field name is `AMAZINGFIELDNAME` then:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\(\s*(AMAZINGFIELDNAME)\s+BETWEEN\s+&amp;\1\s+AND\s+&amp;\1\s*\)");
resultString = regexObj.Replace(subjectString, "(date(digits($1) CONCAT '000000') <= current date and date(digits($1) CONCAT '000000') >= current date)");
```

#### Replace all BETWEEN statements including any with characters "&" and ";"

Will match the following:

- `( WAEXD8 BETWEEN &amp;WAEXD8 AND &amp;WAEXD8 )`
- `( WAEXD8 BETWEEN &amp;WAEXD8&A;NY1 AND &amp;WAEXD&8ANY2 )`
- `( FIELDEXAMPLE1 BETWEEN &amp;FIELDEXAMPLE2 AND &amp;FIELDEXAMPLE2 )`

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\(\s*(\w+)\s+BETWEEN\s+[\w&;]+\s+AND\s+[\w&;]+\s*\)");
resultString = regexObj.Replace(subjectString, "(date(digits($1) CONCAT '000000') <= current date and date(digits($1) CONCAT '000000') >= current date)");
```

Comment: Yes it did really well...and I didn't comment then...sorry for this delay.